# How can I draw an arrow like this whose type is different from the default type using Tikz?

Tags: tikz-pgf, arrows, tikz-arrows

How can I draw an arrow like this whose type is different from the default type using Tikz?

I want one like this: [image]

not like this default type: [image]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You may try `arrows={-Computer Modern Rightarrow[line cap=round]}`, `arrows={Latex}` or `arrows={-Triangle}` via the TikZ library [`arrows.meta`](http://texdoc.net/texmf-dist/doc/generic/pgf/pgfmanual.pdf#page=203):

[image]

```
\documentclass[tikz,margin=1mm]{standalone}
\usetikzlibrary{arrows.meta}
\begin{document}
\begin{tikzpicture}[line width=1mm]
  \draw[blue,arrows={-Computer Modern Rightarrow[line cap=round]}]
  (0,0) -- (1,0);

  \draw[red,arrows={-Latex}]
  (0,1) -- (1,1);

  \draw[green,arrows={-Triangle}]
  (0,2) -- (1,2);
\end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```

**Note:** You may configure the appearance of arrows via some parameters like `length` or `width`:

```
\draw[green,arrows={-Triangle[length=7mm,width=3mm]}] (0,2) -- (1,2);
```

All *Arrow Keys* are described in [section 16.3 "Arrow Keys: Configuring the Appearance of a Single Arrow Tip", p.185, pgfmanual](http://texdoc.net/texmf-dist/doc/generic/pgf/pgfmanual.pdf#page=185)

Comment: Thanks a lot. And I want to change the size of the triangle. I use \draw[green,arrows={-Triangle[]minimum height=balbla.... }], it doesn't work. Could you please fix this problem for me?

Comment: `minimum height=...` should be between `[...]`.

Comment: Sorry, I mean I just type minimum height between [...], but it doesn't work. My file can't compile successfully.

Comment: @LuZhang `minimum height` is not a legal _arrow keys_...